# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory ERROR when trying to copy images into another file

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to copy 90% of images of a source file into a training folder but I have the following error:

```
IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-e1fe9ed34fea> in <module>
     50 
     51 split_size = .9
---> 52 split_data(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_CATS_DIR, TESTING_CATS_DIR, split_size)
     53 split_data(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR, TESTING_DOGS_DIR, split_size)

<ipython-input-24-e1fe9ed34fea> in split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE)
     33     for i in training_set:
     34         if os.path.getsize(SOURCE + i) != 0:
---> 35             copyfile(SOURCE+i, TRAINING)
     36 
     37     for j in testing_set:

/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    119     else:
    120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
--> 121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
    123     return dst

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats'
```

This is my code:

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    list = os.listdir(SOURCE)
    
    images_list = random.sample(list, len(list))
    training_set = []
    testing_set = []
    split_len = int(SPLIT_SIZE*len(list))
    for image in range(len(list)):
        if image >= split_len:
            testing_set.append(list[image])
        else:
            training_set.append(list[image])
        
    for i in training_set:
        if os.path.getsize(SOURCE + i) != 0:
            copyfile(SOURCE+i, TRAINING) 
    
    for j in testing_set:
        if os.path.getsize(SOURCE + j) != 0:
            copyfile(SOURCE+j, TESTING)


CAT_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Cat/"
TRAINING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats"
TESTING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats"
DOG_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Dog/"
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs"
TESTING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs"

split_size = .9
split_data(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_CATS_DIR, TESTING_CATS_DIR, split_size)
split_data(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR, TESTING_DOGS_DIR, split_size)
```

I think the error is in the function copyfile() but I was sure that I was putting the right paths as arguments, where `copyfile(SOURCE+i, TRAINING)` is supposed to copy the image in the source file to the training directory.
I would appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `copyfile` with the wrong destination path.
According to the Python docs you need to give the full path with filename.

`TRAINING_CATS_DIR` is a directory so it gives the `IsADirectoryError`

Sidenote: Don't use `list` as a list variable. `list` is an inbuilt variable in Python.

Answer (score 1):

join the image name to the source and destination path

```
copyfile(os.path.join(source,i) ,os.path.join(training,i))
```